# SQL1585N A temporary table could not be created

Tags: database, import, db2, export

I export db from another system and want to import it by my local system. but as I try to import it, I face this error:

> SQL3015N  An SQL error "-1585" occurred during processing.
>
> SQL1585N  A temporary table could not be created because there is no
> available system temporary table space that has a compatible page
> size.  SQLSTATE=54048

can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get help quicker by searching the Db2 Knowledge Centre online for the error code SQL1585N.

See this [page](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=messages-sql1500-sql1749#sql1585n) for the explanation and the user response.

See also the instructions for [creating a bufferpool](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-create-bufferpool).

See also the instructions for [creating a system temporary tablespace](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-create-tablespace)

You need to run `create system temporary tablespace pagesize ....` statement after you first determine which pagesize you need, which can be 4k, 8k, 16k, 32k . This is simple database administration, and your account needs to have the relevant permissions and authorities to be able to run these statements. If your account lacks relevant rights, ask your DBA for help.

Sometimes you must also pre-create a bufferpool of matching pagesize if one does not already exist, and specify that new bufferpool name when you create the new system temporary tablespace.

Other questions already answer this with examples, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25639962/sufficient-page-size-does-not-exist-db2-insert/53710882#53710882).

If you are copying a database from the same cpu-architecture and same operating-system, the often it is easier to use a redirected restore , instead of using import/load/ingest - especially if you have a full offline Db2-backup taken at the source system.

Comment: I tried this and was successfull:
1. Create a bufferpool with pagesize 32k and adjust the size yourself. 
(db2 create bufferpool bp32k size 1000 pagesize 32k)

2. Create temp space, automatic storage

(db2 create system temporary tablespace tempts32k pagesize 32k bufferpool bp32k)

After the establishment is completed, query again, success! ! !